# C++ - std::function as parameter for a functor

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

I wrote an `Event` class as a wrapper around callback functions, implemented as `std::function`s. This is what it looks like:

```
class Event
{
public:
    Event() : default_handler([]() {});
    Event(const std::function<void()> handler) : default_handler(handler);

    void SetHandler(std::function<void()> handler)
    {
        custom_handler = handler;
    }

    void operator()(void)
    {
        default_handler();
        custom_handler();
    }

private:
    const std::function<void()> default_handler;
    std::function<void()> custom_handler;
};
```

Then, inside another class, I have an instance of an Event:

```
class Control
{
public:
    Control();

//Should call constructor Event()
    Event myEvent1;
//Should call constructor Event(std::function<void()>)
    Event myEvent2([]() {/*do stuff... */})
};
```

This, however, won't compile on VC++, generating error C3646 (unknown override specifier) and error C4430 (missing type specifier - int assumed) for both handlers, with more syntax errors for myEvent2. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: In the future, post the actual errors.  Despite the fact you may not understand them, they actually have useful information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `{}` syntax:

```
Event myEvent2{[]() {/*do stuff... */}};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47080f6ba1777a3a)

As syntax for [default member initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) is

```
member = value;
```

or

```
member{value};
```

but NOT

```
member(value); // Invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you explain *why*?

Comment: @erip: Nothing to do with type erasure, but with allowed syntax to set the default member initializer. see [data_members_initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization)

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
Event myEvent2([]() {/*do stuff... */});
```

compiler treats myEvent2 as the member function, not constructor call.